# Read value of specific child node using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml

I have a small question. My XML document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BACKUP>
  <HEAD>
    <NAME>Test</NAME>
    <DATE>19.05.2015 17:05:42</DATE>
  </HEAD>
  <DIRECTORYSRC>
    <SOURCEDIR>C:\Users\User\Pictures</SOURCEDIR>
  </DIRECTORYSRC>
  <DIRECTORYTRG>
    <TARGETDIR>D:\_backup</TARGETDIR>
  </DIRECTORYTRG>
</BACKUP>
```

What is the best way to read the content of `NAME` and `TARGETDIR` value? Is there a simple way to read only these specific nodes?

And what if I have more then one `TARGETDIR` node? Can I do this by using a `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this using LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);    
var name = (string)doc.Descendants("NAME").Single();
var targetDirs = doc.Descendants("TARGETDIR").Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
```

`name` contains your single `NAME` value, and `targetDirs` is a `List<string>` containing all `TARGETDIR` values.

Comment: Thank you very mutch. Thas it. But i use it with the LOAD command        var doc = XDocument.Load(item);
    var name = (string)doc.Descendants("NAME").Single();

Comment: Depends where you XML is, `Parse` takes an xml string, whereas `Load` will take a file path, stream, or text/xml reader.